# Method to find and set base URL automatically to a jquery script

Tags: jquery, json

I have a Jquery Ajax search plugin,

It works by site url. Is there any way get URL automatically see below:

```
var searchFormConfig = {
   url: "http://search-test-site.com/",  //Search Site URL

   numPost: 100,     //Number Of Search Results
   summaryPost: true,    //enable-disable Search Result Summary
   summaryLength: 400,    //Search Result Summary Length in words
   resultTitle: "SEARCH RESULTS FOR", //Search Result Container Title
   noResult: "No result",    //No Result Tittle
   resultThumbnail: true,    //enable-disable Search Result Thumbnail
   thumbSize: 110,    //Search Result Thumbnail Size in px
   fallbackThumb: "/no-img.jpg" //No Thumbnail
};
```

I mean any way, without putting site URL, script will find base URL automatically ? Like This:

```
 var searchFormConfig = {
   url: " location.href ",  //Search Site URL
```

I'm learning jquery so i don't know, how Script will find site URL automatically.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
var searchFormConfig = {
   url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/",  //Search Site URL
```